# Ruby best way to make this string an array?

Tags: ruby, parsing

What is the best way to make a string that looks like an array of hashes into a real array?

The string looks something like this: `[{name:"lol", age:12},{name:"lmao", age:66},{name: "roflcopter", age:99}]`
and I need to get exactly the same but as an array.

Input: (a string)

```
'[{name:"lol", age:12},{name:"lmao", age:66},{name: "roflcopter", age:99}]'
```

Expected output: (an array of hashes)

```
[{name:"lol", age:12},{name:"lmao", age:66},{name: "roflcopter", age:99}]
```

Comment: What is the input? What have you tried so far?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Array of what? names? ages? both? Please give us a more detailed example

Comment: @whodini9 updated the question

Comment: Where does the string come from?

Comment: @Stefan a post request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your string is very similar to, but not *quite* the same as JSON. This means you have three choices.

---

## 1) Convert it to JSON (upstream)

The only difference between your string and a proper JSON string is that in JSON, all keys need to be wrapped in quotes. If you have control over the format of your string, I suggest you change it to be in JSON format:

```
'[{"name":"lol", "age":12},{"name":"lmao", "age":66},{"name": "roflcopter", "age":99}]'
```

Once the string is in this format, you can turn it into an array of hashes using `JSON.parse`:

```
require "json"
source_string = '[{"name":"lol", "age":12},{"name":"lmao", "age":66},{"name": "roflcopter", "age":99}]'
data = JSON.parse source_string
puts data[0] #=> {"name"=>"lol", "age"=>12}
```

I *highly* recommend this course of action. The included JSON parser handles all string validation in a secure way. Moreover, JSON is basically designed for providing arrays and hashes in string form. It is a well-accepted standard that people will understand.

---

## 2) Convert it to JSON (downstream)

If for some reason you cannot update your source string to be JSON by default (maybe you're working with a third party who refuses to adopt a better standard), you can programmatically modify the string to be in the proper JSON format. I actually went ahead and wrote a regex which will put the proper quotes around the string:

```
source_string = '[{name:"lol", age:12},{name:"lmao", age:66},{name: "roflcopter", age:99}]'
json_string = source_string.gsub /(?<=[{,])\s*(\w+)(?=:)/, '"\1"'
data = JSON.parse json_string
puts data[0] #=> {"name"=>"lol", "age"=>12}
```

---

## 3) Use eval

Your string, in its current format, is valid ruby code. Which means you can use `eval` to execute it as ruby code:

```
data = eval('[{name:"lol", age:12},{name:"lmao", age:66},{name: "roflcopter", age:99}]')
puts data[0] #=>{name: "lol", age: 12}
```

The issue with `eval`, and the reason I and many other people will strongly advise against it, is that it's incredibly insecure. You said the data was coming from a POST request- if your user happens to modify the request to send the string "system('rm *')", your code will execute:

```
eval("system('rm *')")
```

Which, as you may have guessed, will wipe your harddrive. You can try to write string validation to make sure the string is safe before running `eval`, but that sort of validation is not an easy task, and the `eval` will likely always be the weakest point in your code, from a security standpoint.

Honestly, there's no reason you should do this, especially since option #2 is so wonderfully straight-forward. I only mention it so you know to avoid it.

Comment: 2) will fail if a string contains a match to the regex.

Comment: @CameronMartin do you mean there are situations with #2 where a valid string would be improperly `gsub`-ed and would throw an error?

Comment: Excellent answer!

Comment: Consider the string `'{ name: "foo:" }'`. `foo:` would incorrectly match the regex.

Comment: @CameronMartin oh you're right! thank you for catching that; i'll update my answer with a fix. (this is why it's better to have the string as JSON upstream :T )

Comment: Good catch, @Cameron. Fixing is not so easy if keys can have non-word characters. A start might be the following (to only modify keys): `i=-1; json_string = source_string.gsub(/(\w+):/) { |s| i+=1; i.even? ? "\"#{s}\":" : s }`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Although not terribly clear, the OP implies that the input is ruby source code. So, the best way to parse it would be to use a ruby parser. Or roll your own for this limited subset of the ruby language using something like [treetop](https://github.com/nathansobo/treetop). I don't believe that regular expressions are the best tool for this.

Comment: eiko and @cameron, my earlier suggestion was not well thought out. What about enclosing both keys and values in double quotes, retrieve the hash and then change the values back?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I agree that we were probably pushing the limits of where regex should be used, but it's too late to turn back now! >:3  After sleeping on it, I came up with a regex that uses lookahead for a `{` or `,` to determine that a key is in fact a key. It's not perfect because it deletes any whitespace between the key and the `{` or `,`, but since that whitespace is aesthetic in this case, I figured it'd be good enough.

Comment: @eiko Then that will fail on `'{ name: "foo: {" }'`

Comment: @CameronMartin does stackoverflow have an "I surrender" button?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the first choice would be to not send the data as ruby source code. However, if you really have to do this:

If the input is from a trusted source, you can use [`eval`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-eval).

Otherwise, you could parse the string using a [ruby parser](https://github.com/whitequark/parser) and then generate your arrays and hashes from the AST.

Comment: unfortunately, it's not JSON. The keys need to be surrounded in quotes. it's a minor difference, but enough to break the parser.

Comment: Ah yes, didn't see that.

Comment: yea, also the source is not secure please delete this answer.

Comment: The idea of using a ruby parser in ruby is wacky, but I love it ^-^